# XSLT to concatenate element name with attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt

how could I make out of an XML like this:

```
<nameGroup index="1"> 
    <name>SOME NAME</name>
    <country>CN</country>
</nameGroup>
<nameGroup index="2">
    <name>SOME OTHER NAME</name>
    <country>IQ</country>
</nameGroup>
```

To an XML like this, concatenating element name with attribute value:

```
<nameGroup><name1>SOME NAME</name1><country1>CN</country1></nameGroup>
<nameGroup><name2>SOME OTHER NAME</name2><country2>IQ</country2></nameGroup>
```

with a proper XSLT?

I tried with something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="nameGroup/name">
      <xsl:variable name="pos">
          <xsl:number count="info"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}{$pos}">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
   
   <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the result is just something like this:

```
<nameGroup>1 
  <name>SOME NAME</name>
  <country>CN</country>
</nameGroup>
<nameGroup>2
  <name>SOME OTHER NAME</name>
  <country>IQ</country>
 </nameGroup>
```

Anyone knows how can I obtain the desired result?
Thanks!

PS: I made it like this (if anyone would search for this in the future):
(with mr. Michael Kay's help)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}{../@index}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="* | node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: 1. Are you sure you want to do this? The result will be much harder to process than the original. 2. Please ask a **specific** question about a difficulty you encountered when trying to accomplish this. Otherwise it looks like you're just looking for someone to write your code for you.

Comment: Sorry @michael.hor257k, I edited the question with what I tried. Yes, I need an result just like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't imagine why anyone would want to do this; I also can't see why you find it difficult. You simply need the rule

```
<xsl:template match="namegroup/*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}{../@index}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```